# How to refresh font-lock of the current buffer?

Tags: font-lock

I have a function to highlight custom Scheme syntax:

```lisp
(defun scheme-defmacro (syntax &optional args)
  (let ((args (or args 1)))
    (put syntax 'scheme-indent-function args))
  (let ((regexp (concat "(\\<\\(" (symbol-name syntax) "\\)\\>")))
    (font-lock-add-keywords 'scheme-mode
                            `((,regexp 1 font-lock-keyword-face)))))
```

The function works but affects only newly created Scheme buffers. How to update the highlighting of the current buffer, if the major mode is `scheme-mode`?

I tried this (because of a SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1445212/402322)), but it does not work:

```
(if (eq major-mode 'scheme-mode)
    (font-lock-fontify-buffer))
```

Comment: I don't have a solution to whatever the overall issue may be, but wanted to mention that I manually use `jit-lock-refontify` occasionally -- the argument `BEG` could either be `(point-min)` or `(window-start WIN)` and the argument `END` could be either `(point-max)` or `(window-end WIN t)`.

Comment: Typically, you add keywords either before you open any buffers, or in the major mode hook. That way you don't have the problem with updating existing buffers.

Comment: You could simply restart the major mode, then it will pick up the new keywords

Comment: @Lindydancer In Scheme the keywords depend on the syntax you define. Because of that, I like to have `scheme-defmacro` in a comment next to `define-syntax` in the same Scheme source file.